# Deleting the checked items in the listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to make an app which includes a `listView` with check boxes and a two buttons named `add` and `delete selected`. I want to delete all the item that are checked in the list view.I am unable to do that despite of my lot of efforts. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
package com.example.chkbokinlistview;

public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movies> {

    ArrayList<Movies> data;
    Context context;
    int id;
    private Holder h;

    public Adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Movies> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.data = objects;
        this.context = context;
        this.id = textViewResourceId;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int p = position;
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater l = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        h = new Holder();
        if (v == null) {
            v = l.inflate(id, parent, false);
            h.tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            h.cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            v.setTag(h);
        }else{
            h = (Holder) v.getTag();
            h.cb.setChecked(true);
        }
        h.tv.setText(data.get(position).movieName);
        h.cb.setChecked(data.get(position).deleted);
        return v;
    }
    public void delete(){
        //how to delete all the items that are checked
    }

     class Holder{
        TextView tv;
        CheckBox cb;
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        bDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDelete);
        bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);

        list = new ArrayList<Movies>();
        a = new Adapter(this, R.layout.listitem, list);
        lv.setAdapter(a);

        bDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                a.delete();
            }
        });
        bAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final EditText et = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        list.add(new Movies(et.getText().toString(), false));
                        a.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setTitle("ADD Movie")
                .setView(et)
                .create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The title is incredibly misleading. ;-)

Comment: yes it is @IceMAN just edited it. hope they accept the title I suggested. any title is better than this though. ;)

Comment: so what's happening? Or not happening? And what have you tried? You've got to ask specific questions if you want to leverage this site. We're not going to do your work for you, but we'll help you do it yourself :)

Comment: What about keeping in model Movies field that will hold current state (checked / unchecked) of object?.. And if user clicks on checkbox, this field will change. And if user wants to delete checked movies, you can just remove from movie list all objects that are checked and call notifyDataSetChanged(). What do you think about this proposal?

Comment: ohh ;-) that was the title of my last question that is decided to not post at the last moment.

Answer (score 1):

On checking the `checkbox` add that `position` in an `ArrayList` let say `toBeDeleted`, and when you click delete button, just remove items from your `ArrayList` named `data` according to the positions that you have in `toBeDeleted` and call the adapter method `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

---

Add a `checkedChangedListener` in the `getView` method for your `CheckBox`.

```
h.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                            boolean arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (arg1) {
                            list.add(position);
                        } else {
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                if (list.get(i) == position) {
                                    list.remove(i);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Where list is a `ArrayList<Integer>`,
and for deleting

```
private void delete() {
    for(int i = 0 i<list.size;i++)
        data.remove(list.get(i));
}
```

but before deleting you have to sort the `list` in decending order, in order to remove correctly, otherwise you may get an `IndexOutofBoundException`

Comment: @anujMathus i tried it. but i am unable to click my list item. i mean it is not responding to the event. if i replace checkbox with imageView then it works fine.

Comment: @Usman Riaz: I have updated the answer. Try it. hope its helpful... :)

Comment: i appriciate your ans  but i already solv my problem . see my ans

Comment: I think u should `accept` any answer. If you find the solution then accept it.

Comment: i know hot head. i posted my ans and i can not accept my own ans with in 2 days.